# how to add https:// protocol on IIS6 to windows server 2008

Tags: javascript, asp.net, https

Currently I am working on Quality control project. The requirement is that i want location from where user entering data that location By using java script , I got on local server but whenever I hos my website on main Server there is error that 
 After Chrome 50 version it requires **HTTPS** protocol only , for that i want to add **HTTPS** protocol on server.After adding **SSL** certificate it not works.

[image: Thanks]

Comment: Do you have an SSL certificate? D̶i̶d̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶ ̶a̶ ̶s̶e̶a̶r̶c̶h̶ ̶e̶n̶g̶i̶n̶e̶?̶
 (sorry, that was cheeky)

Comment: Yes i added @evolutionxbox

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] of the web.config file?

Comment: You have to also configure the bindings of the website, in IIS right click on the website and click "edit bindings" > click add > select https from the dropdown > Select your cert and then try and navigate to your site over https

Comment: Yes @George i done this but after on web site its not showing https secured protocol , it showing not secured protocol

Comment: You still need to navigate to `https://yourwebsite`, if you navigate to `http://yourwebsite` it will not use the SSL

Comment: No @evolutionxbox i didn't see search engine #@@@**

Comment: I think so @George you r right thats not using **SSL** protocol but already i have added SSL certificate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS HTTP to HTTPS relative redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756774/iis-http-to-https-relative-redirect)

Comment: Why Down Voted?????

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup SSL feature on your server. There is [How to Set Up SSL on IIS 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis) manual about about. Create an SSL binding on your web-node and configure SSL settings after adding SSL certificate.
It is also need to use trusted certificate authorities and setting up certificate chain right to achive "This Site is Safe" checkmark in a browser. Detailed instruction you can get from your certificate issuer.